# Change according to input check

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i solve this problem: i have many inputs on the page.
when I click on an input and it is check it has to change the color to the label depending on it

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('label.boxextra').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
      if ($("input[type='checkbox']").is(':checked')) {
        $('label.boxextra').css('background-color', 'red');
      } else {
        $('label.boxextra').css('background-color', '#fff');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
label.boxextra {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #D4D4D4;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="extra_0" style="display:inline; margin-right: 10px;" class="boxextra"><input type="checkbox" data-multiple="1" id="extra_0" name="extra[]" value="rosii"> rosii</label>

<label for="extra_1" style="display:inline; margin-right: 10px;" class="boxextra"><input type="checkbox" data-multiple="1" id="extra_1" name="extra[]" value="castraveti"> castraveti</label></td>
```

Comment: replace  $('label.boxextra').css('background-color', 'red'); with $(this).css('background-color', 'red');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").is(':checked')
```

to

```
$("input", this).is(':checked')
```

and

```
$('label.boxextra').css('background-color', 'red');
```

to

```
$(this).css('background-color', 'red');
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('label.boxextra').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
      if ($("input", this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
      } else {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#fff');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
label.boxextra {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #D4D4D4;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="extra_0" style="display:inline; margin-right: 10px;" class="boxextra"><input type="checkbox" data-multiple="1" id="extra_0" name="extra[]" value="rosii"> rosii</label>

<label for="extra_1" style="display:inline; margin-right: 10px;" class="boxextra"><input type="checkbox" data-multiple="1" id="extra_1" name="extra[]" value="castraveti"> castraveti</label></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

find relative elements inside using `this` bound to your listener

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('label.boxextra').each(function() {
    var label = $(this);
    label.click(function() {
      if (label.find("input[type='checkbox']").is(':checked')) {
        label.css('background-color', 'red');
      } else {
        label.css('background-color', '#fff');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
label.boxextra {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #D4D4D4;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="extra_0" style="display:inline; margin-right: 10px;" class="boxextra"><input type="checkbox" data-multiple="1" id="extra_0" name="extra[]" value="rosii"> rosii</label>

<label for="extra_1" style="display:inline; margin-right: 10px;" class="boxextra"><input type="checkbox" data-multiple="1" id="extra_1" name="extra[]" value="castraveti"> castraveti</label></td>
```

Comment: Why assigning the click event to the label? It's the checkbox click/change that we are targeting.

Comment: event bubbling so that the whole acts as a component rather than only clicking the checkbox @AnisR.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can have a click event on each checkbox, and use the checkbox's `id` to change the color of the right label (based on the label's `for`) accordingly.

And on a side note, in your original code, why looping over the labels and using `$(this).click` inside the loop, when `$("label.boxextra").click` is a quicker way of doing the same thing?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
    //if it's checked assign 'color' to red, else white
    color = this.checked ? "red" : "#fff";
    $("label[for='" + this.id + "']").css("background-color", color);
  });
});
```

```css
label.boxextra {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #D4D4D4;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="extra_0" style="display:inline; margin-right: 10px;" class="boxextra"><input type="checkbox" data-multiple="1" id="extra_0" name="extra[]" value="rosii"> rosii</label>

<label for="extra_1" style="display:inline; margin-right: 10px;" class="boxextra"><input type="checkbox" data-multiple="1" id="extra_1" name="extra[]" value="castraveti"> castraveti</label></td>
```

Comment: @PruteanuAlexandru Glad this helps! If this post answered your question, please consider marking it as answer. Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

Set up the code to read the color from the label ids:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('label.boxextra').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
      if (!$(this).find('input').is(':checked')) {
        $(this).find('input').prop('checked', true);
        $(this).css('background-color', $(this).find('input').attr('id'));
      } else {
        $(this).find('input').prop('checked', false);
        $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
label.boxextra {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #D4D4D4;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="extra_0" style="display:inline; margin-right: 10px;" class="boxextra">
  <input type="checkbox" data-multiple="1" id="red" name="extra" value="rosii"> 
  red
</label>

<label for="extra_1" style="display:inline; margin-right: 10px;" class="boxextra">
  <input type="checkbox" data-multiple="1" id="green" name="extra" value="castraveti"> 
  green
</label>

<label for="extra_1" style="display:inline; margin-right: 10px;" class="boxextra">
  <input type="checkbox" data-multiple="1" id="blue" name="extra" value="castraveti"> 
  blue
</label>
```

Comment: Why assigning the click event to the label? We are targeting the checkboxes' click/change event, and it's the checkbox value that we want to track!

Comment: The code in the question shows that's what the user wanted.